# C++ template argument as reference lvalue

Tags: c++, templates

I am reading "Game programming gems" book. I am currently implementing sine example:

```
//Sine class
template<double &x, unsigned N>
struct Sine
{
    static constexpr double val = x * (1.0 - x * x / (2.0 * N + 2) / (2.0 * N + 3)) * Sine<x,N+1>::val;;
};
//
template<const double &x>
struct Sine<x, 10>
{
    static constexpr double val = 1.0;
};
```

I am trying to call my template value with:

```
constexpr double x = 1.234;
cout << "Sine<1.234,0>::val = " << Sine<x, 0>::val << endl;
```

It cause error:

> error: 'x' is not a valid template argument for type 'double&' because
>   of conflicts in cv-qualification|

I dont have idea what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point types cannot be non-type template parameters. Thus the author of the template took a reference to a `double` instead.

Your code has two problems. First of all, an argument to such a reference must have static storage duration and linkage, which your variable cannot have both as it is defined in block-scope. Secondly, your variable is `const` (as it is `constexpr`), and a non-`const` reference cannot be bound to a `const` object.

Change the template parameter to `double const&` and pass a namespace-scope `constexpr` object of type `double` as the template argument.

Comment: And additionally consider changing the templates to `constexpr` functions for clearer code and faster compilation.

Comment: Thank You!I understood two things: 1)It HAS to be external linkage(e.g.: extern namespace arguments{ constexpr double x = 1.234;} and than Sine<arguments::x,0> and 2)i just forgot about const keyword when i pass const ereference :D, external linkage hast to be done with argument because template are "happening" when compiling isn't ?